# Google map not shown?

Tags: android, kotlin

Searched every where what i did

1- created key in google console

2- enabled google maps for android

3- manifest

```
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="keyHere" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

4- added the fragment called async and still `override fun onMapReady(p0: GoogleMap?) {` not called

Answer (score 0):

You might need a few more permissions up at the top:

```
<!--  Google Maps V2 API -->
<permission android:name="com.mycompany.myapp.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission 
android:name="com.mycompany.myapp.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```